# Using Exists Clause in IIF Statement

Tags: ms-access

Can we use Exists Clause in IIF Statement. I want to order the output based on certain condition.

```
Select *
From Table1 AS a
Order By IIF( Exists(Select * From Table2 Where Col_Name='Criteria'),a.Col1,a.Col2) Desc
```

not getting the result in MS Access.

Comment: It's not clear from your code or your description what your intended order is. Please share some sample data and your desired results.

Comment: `Select * From Table2 Where Col_Name='Criteria'` will always return something, right?Therefore, checking to see if `EXISTS()` will always be true. So `a.Col1` will always be used for ordering. So you'll have to JOIN `table2` to `table1` in your FROM clause for your `IIF()` or... you will need to "Correlate" yoursubquery like `SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE col_name=`Criteria` AND a.some_field = table2.some_field` If you share sample data and desired results, we can help write that.

Comment: @Jnevill No not neccesary that the condition is met.

Comment: Exists clause is not working inside the IIF Statement.

Comment: "Not working" is meaningless. Does it error, does it give unexpected results? "Not necessary that the condition is met" and yet that condition is ALWAYS met in ALL cases the way it's written. You might as well put `IIF(TRUE, col1, col2)` it would yield the same results.

Comment: it gives error that the syntax is incorrect.

Comment: I understand that it's not what you want, but try removing that `DESC` hanging out at the end and see if that's causing the syntax error. Also, try tossing the `IIF(EXISTS())` up into the SELECT clause as a new field and see if it spits out what you want. You could always just use the result of that to order (assuming it runs).

Comment: ms-access does not use t-sql... edited your tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider `DLookUp` or `DCount` domain functions as `EXISTS` clause does not work in expressions for MS Access:

```
Select *
From Table1 AS a
Order By IIF(DLookUp("Col_Name", "Table2", "Col_Name='Criteria'") IS NOT NULL, a.Col1, a.Col2) Desc

Select *
From Table1 AS a
Order By IIF(DCount("*", "Table2", "Col_Name='Criteria'") > 0, a.Col1, a.Col2) Desc
```